# How can I get re.sub() to ignore a question mark in pattern?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to strip urls from a long file.
My code is working fine except this one instance (below). 
I believe the problem is that the url string has a ?. 
How can deal with this case in the body of my loop?
How can I force re.sub() ignore the ? in the url variable?

```
blah = 'City of San Jose. Playa to Paseo, http://www.sanjoseca.gov/index.aspx?nid=5876'
url='http://www.sanjoseca.gov/index.aspx?nid=5876'
re.sub(url,'',blah)

OUT>>'City of San Jose. Playa to Paseo, http://www.sanjoseca.gov/index.aspx?nid=5876'

Desired OUT>>> 'City of San Jose. Playa to Paseo, '
```

Edit: To manually fix every url in the whole file with a weird character
is not what I want to do. I am looping over 1000's of lines with urls here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly escape all of the special characters in the regular expression to match a literal character. This includes the periods as well:

```
blah = 'City of San Jose. Playa to Paseo, http://www.sanjoseca.gov/index.aspx?nid=5876'
url='http://www\.sanjoseca\.gov/index\.aspx\?nid=5876'
print(re.sub(url,'',blah))
```

Or, you can use `re.escape` to do it for you:

```
blah = 'City of San Jose. Playa to Paseo, http://www.sanjoseca.gov/index.aspx?nid=5876'
url = re.escape('http://www.sanjoseca.gov/index.aspx?nid=5876')
print(re.sub(url,'',blah))
```

Comment: From the documentation: "[re.escape] must not be used for the replacement string in sub() and subn(), only backslashes should be escaped."